# Gallery. Display divs corresponding to clicked <li> item. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a basic gallery which displays a large image [div] depending on which image is clicked. The thumbnail images are stored in a basic unordered list.

I'm a javascript noob, I could use getElementById to change display class etc but I'd prefer not to have a separate function for each image, of which they're may be 100 or so.

Is there a way to call the same function to display a different div depending on which image is clicked [a larger version of that image]?

So:
If img1 is clicked display divA,
If img2 is clicked display divB,
If img3 is clicked display divC...

Many thanks.

Comment: Add your complete HTML, Javascript, CSS code. A working jsfiddle will be better

Answer (score 0):

The event passed to the `onclick` method has a `target` parameter, which refers to the element that was clicked.

Please post your code, preferably in a working JsFiddle, to get a more targeted answer.

Here is a general example of what you want to achieve:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    // e.target is the img that was clicked, display the corresponding div

    // Get the image number from the id
    var number = e.target.id.substr(3)

    // Display the corresponding div
    document.getElementById('div' + number).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Please note that the last line will most likely be different in your implementation - I don't know how you are displaying these divs.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'll try this. I'll post a jsFiddle if i have any issues… I knew there'd be basic answer to use as a starting point.

Comment: Good to hear. Please accept my answer as correct if it works for you!

Comment: Will do…. Last line is fine, I'm using 'visibility'.

Comment: In my humble opinion, there may be issues with the above code. `onclick` will be here triggered for any clicks anywhere on the document. Also `e` will be the deepest clicked element in the dom tree, which means that if there is anything inside the element to click (e.g. a label), it will be `e` (though it may not be much of a problem for images that usually do not have children).

Answer (score -1):

You could try as follows

> Assign id to all images in such a manner when they will be clicked we 
>   could generate the corresponding div's id with some logical
>   manipulation.

Such as

images would have id like img_divA,img_divB and when they will be clicked , get there id and do some stuff like substring and you will get divA , divB and so on .. Finally show that by javascript ..

Comment: I don't think this answer is particularly useful as you haven't provided any code.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this. Here actually a function is created per clickable dom element, but they are programmatically created. I use the `num` attribute to make the correspondence between the images to show and the images to click but there is many other (good) ways to do it.

```js
// retrieve the divs to be clicked
var toClicks = document.querySelectorAll(".img-to-click");
[].forEach.call(toClicks, function(node){
  // retrieve the target image
  var num = node.getAttribute("num");
  var target = document.querySelector(".img-to-show[num=\"" + num + "\"]");
  // create the click listener on this particular dom element
  // (one of the image to click)
  node.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // hide any currently displayed image
    var current = document.querySelector(".img-to-show.shown");
    if(current) current.classList.remove("shown");
    // set the new current
    target.classList.add("shown");
  });
});
```

```css
#to-display {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#to-click {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.img-to-show {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.img-to-show.shown {
  display: block; 
}

.img-to-click{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50px;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="to-display">
    <div class="img-to-show" num="1" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div class="img-to-show" num="2" style="background-color:red;"></div>
</div>

<div id="to-click">
    <div class="img-to-click" num="1">1</div>
    <div class="img-to-click" num="2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this fits very well with what the asker's code currently does. Of course, it's impossible to tell without access to the code!

Comment: Here's the basics. The file as a whole is quite complex and there are other scripts running, which may be causing issues. This is the idea though… https://jsfiddle.net/6aqa4ccw/1/

Images in the list items should be clicked to display the corresponding image in the divs above.

Comment: @Sam I don't really see why not. Can you explain?

Comment: I did a little something you could have a look as a proof of concept here: http://jsfiddle.net/1vozbz0m/9/. Obviously the images cannot be found in the jsfiddle you gave us so you do not really see anything happening. But if you look at the inspector you will see it working.

Comment: I tried not to touch at your html but using classes or attributes would definitely make everything easier (and cleaner).